# Serialize JSON using ObjectContent issue

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, serialization, json.net

I wrote a HTTP client library which is used by one of our existing process. It sends a post request with a JSON content in the body. The code that populates the request content and the object itself look like below.

```
… 
        HttpRequestMessage httpMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost");
        MyWireObject request = new MyWireObject()
        {
            Email = "user@test.com",
            Document = JToken.Parse(@"{""content"": ""data"", ""content2"": ""data2""}")
        };
        httpMessage.Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(MyWireObject), request, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        //httpMessage.Content = new StringContent(JToken.FromObject(request).ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var content = httpMessage.Content;
        string jsonContent = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
…

public class MyWireObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Email")]
    public string Email
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Document")]
    public JToken Document
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

When I use the client library with a standalone exe I wrote, it serialize the JSON just fine. But when I integrate it with the existing process, the result (which is captured in jsonContent) looks something like this:

```
{"Email":"user@test.com","Document":{"content":[],"content2":[]} }
```

Basically, all the values of the JToken field are lost. If I use StringContent instead of ObjectContent, as in the commented line, it works.

One difference I could think of between my standalone exe and the existing process is that the process runs under network service account. Is this due to account permission? Or am I using it wrong? Or is it due to some known bug in .NET or Newtonsoft.Json.Linq?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take a different approach and use Newtonsoft.Json:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

// First define the classes you will need ...

public class Document
{
    public string Content1 { get; set; }
    public string Content2 { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class MyWireObject
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Document Document { get; set; }
}

// Later, create an instance and serialize it as the body of your request ...

HttpRequestMessage httpMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost");
MyWireObject myWireObject = new MyWireObject() 
{
    Email = "user@test.com",
    Document = new Document() 
    {
        Content1 = "content1",
        Content2 = "content2",
        // ...
    }
};

httpMessage.Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myWireObject);

// Later in the POST handler ...

string myWireObjectAsString = httpMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

// Or even better ...

MyWireObject myWireObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyWireObject>(myWireObjectAsString);

// And use the object ...
```